# Counting elements of a particular order -- why is this incorrect?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I have a solution and I compared it to the solution we were given. I have bolded where there is a difference. I don't know why this is incorrect:

> Count the elements of order $10$ in $D_{10} \times \mathbb{Z}_{450}$

My solution: The order of an element in a direct product of groups is the lcm of each component. To obtain order $4$ we can have

- First component $1,2,5$ or $10$, second Component $10$  - this gives $4*(1+11+4+4) = 80$ elements
- Second component $1,2,5$ or $\mathbf{10}$, second Component $10$  - this gives $4*(1+1+4+4) = 40$ elements
- First Component $5$, first component $2$ - this gives $4*1=4$ elements
- First Component $2$, first component $5$ - this gives $11*4=44$ elements

Thus 168 elements of order 10.

Why aren't the order $10$ elements included  in the second bullet point?

Comment: Is $D_{10}$ symmetry group of pentagon?

Comment: No its symmetry group for decagon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second bullet should not count the elements where the first and second component both have order 10, since you already included them in the first bullet.